# Loading and updating Gemfire cache from Oracle table

Tags: java, oracle, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, gemstone

I am new to Pivotal Gemfire and configuring Gemfire to store Oracle table data for low-latency and high throughput application.

Via  there are ways by which we can load the data in to Gemfire cache.

Does anyone know how can I update the data if any update happens in Oracle post Gemfire cache loading?

Any help, directions, references would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would want to design your application such that all updates are flowing from your application through GemFire and then to Oracle.  You could use a GemFire [CacheWriter](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/CacheWriter.html) to update the Oracle database synchronously and even wrap this in a [(JTA) transaction](http://gemfire81.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/transactions/JTA_transactions_with_GemFire.html) so that the Oracle database is only updated if GemFire was successfully updated.  See more details [here](http://gemfire81.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/outside_data_sources/sync_outside_data.html). You can even perform the update asynchronously (write-behind) using AsyncEventQueues and Listeners, see [here](http://gemfire81.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/events/implementing_write_behind_event_handler.html) and more generally [here](http://gemfire81.docs.pivotal.io/latest/userguide/index.html#developing/events/event_handler_overview.html).

It is possible that you have other non-GemFire based applications that access your Oracle database directly.  In this case, you are going to have to rely on external means to detect the database updates and feed them into GemFire.  There are many ways to do this, of course, such as from a scheduled service that periodically checks for database updates and pulls them into GemFire.  A combination of the core Spring Frameworks' [Task Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling) infrastructure combined with [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa) (or even just [Spring's JDBC Abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-introduction)) would greatly simplify this effort.

Or, if it were me, I would probably opt for [Spring XD](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/), and setup a "[stream](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#_create_a_stream)" having a Oracle Database (JDBC) "[source](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jdbc-source)" mixed with some [transformations/filters/etc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#processors) as necessary, and then a GemFire "[sink](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#gemfire-server)".

Hope this helps and good luck.

Cheers!

Comment: Can a synchronous cache writer/listener execute a data aware procedure that intern updates records in other tables and all this to be done in a single transaction?

Comment: Yes, but... you should read this... http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/transactions/data_location_cache_transactions.html.  Essentially, the other tables (or Regions as they are called in GemFire, which is a key/value store (i.e. a Map), and not a tabular data structure) must be colocated with the Region on which the transactional is initially performed.  I.e. all transactional data must reside in the host on which the transaction is initiated.